# Change X-Axis displayed values in Power BI

Tags: graph, charts, powerbi

I have built a bar chart in Power BI

the chart looks fine except the the X-Axis naming is not changeable

I want the data to be sorted the way they are, but the name of each bar is typed differently

[image]

at the moment the X-Axis showing

```
April / May / June / July / etc.
```

I want it to show a different label example

```
4-18 / 5-18 / 6-18 / 7-18 / etc
```

I created a computed column and used the naming I wanted it in it

but the order was wrong in the chart

I got this

```
1-18 / 10-18 / 11-18 / 12-18 / 2-18 / 3-18 / etc.
```

even with leading 0 I got this

```
01-17 / 01-18 / 02-17 / 02-18 / etc.
```

Is there any way I can change the X-Axis label without disturbing its order?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The column you created is sorted as text. That's why `01-18` comes before `02-17`. To sort them by date, you can create another integer column, e.g. `YearMonthKey`, and then sort the column you created (e.g. YearMonthText) based on `YearMonthKey`.

[image: data]

[image: sort by]

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]